# Direct sums of modules versus products

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, projective-module, injective-module

In my module theory course, we recently proved the following theorems:

> For a fixed ring $R$ and index set $I$, let $P_i$ and $Q_i$ be $R$-modules for all $i\in I$. Then $$P=\bigoplus _{i\in I}P_i$$ is projective if and only if each $P_i$ is projective, and $$Q=\prod_{i\in I}Q_i$$ is injective if and only if each $Q_i$ is injective.

But what exactly is the product of modules in the injective case? In our course we showed that the direct sum $M\oplus N$ of two $R$-modules is both the product and coproduct (in the categorical sense), so clearly the injective case is not referring to coproducts.

I tried asking my instructor during class, wondering whether he was simply using different notation for the direct sum, but he only said that the second assertion is not true if one deals with direct sums of modules, so that rules out that theory as well.

My last idea was that it simply meant the Cartesian product in the set theoretical sense, but then what is the module structure?

So, what is the second part of the theorem referring to?

Comment: The second part is referring to usual Cartesian product with module structure defined component-wise. Note that only finite products and coproducts conincide for modules.

Comment: You might also be interested in knowing that every sum (infinite or not) of injective right R modules is injective iff R is right noetherian, and every direct product (infinite or not) of projective right R modules is projective iff R is right perfect and left coherent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of the product of modules in general  is that $R$ is a ring, and $M_i$, $i\in I$ are $R$-modules, then the product $M=\prod_{i\in I}M_i$ is the $R$-module of tuples $\{ (m_i)\mid m_i\in M_i\}$ with componentwise addition and "diagonal" multiplication $r.(m_i)_{i\in I}$. The direct sum $\oplus_{i\in I}M_i$ of $R$-modules $M_i$ is  defined as the submodule of the direct product consisting of all $(m_i)$ satisfying $m_i=0$ for *almost all* $i\in I$. In general, an *infinite* product is not isomorphic to an *infinite* sum. For example, the module $M=\prod_{i\ge 0}\mathbb{Z}$ is not free-abelian, but $N=\oplus_{i\ge 0}\mathbb{Z}$ is free-abelian.

Comment: Let me make sure I understand the difference - direct sums and products have the same module structure, and they both consist of tuples, with the difference being that a direct product can have infinitely many nonzero components, while a direct sum must have all but finitely many components equal to zero?

Comment: Yes, that's it. We need to be a bit careful with the expression "same module structure";  this should mean that we have the same module operation, inherited from the direct product (as a submodule).